# How to retrieve multiple inherited types from a collection in C++?

Tags: c++

Say you have a std::vector class that holds type Item, and you store inherited types of items: Weapon, Potion, Armor, etc. How do you retrieve the item as the inherited class and not the base?

Comment: You need a vector of pointers/references to avoid slicing. Then you need some way to detect the type of the object, either RTTI or a type flag. But the whole point of polymorphism is that you shouldn't need to know exact types.

Comment: [Try visiting the items instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116057/visitor-pattern-explanation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do you retrieve the item as the inherited class and not the base?

This suggests that you need closed-set polymorphism, which is provided by `std::variant` or `boost::variant`.

```
using Entity = std::variant<Weapon, Potion, Armor>;
// An `Entity` is either a `Weapon`, a `Potion`, or an `Armor`.

std::vector<Entity> entities;

struct EntityVisitor
{
    void operator()(Weapon&);
    void operator()(Potion&);
    void operator()(Armor&);
};

for(auto& e : entities)
{
    std::visit(EntityVisitor{}, e);
    // Call the correct overload depending on what `e` is.
}
```

Comment: Interesting. While in the for loop, how do I know 'è' is of type Weapon now, for example? Or does visit() turn e into Weapon?

Comment: @Phil: `visit` handles that for you. If `e` is a weapon, then `EntityVisitor::operator()(Weapon&)` will be called.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are `variant` and `visit` approved? I didn't know they made it into the standard. Notably http://en.cppreference.com doesn't either...

Comment: @JonathanMee - They are in the latest standard draft. http://eel.is/c++draft/variant

Comment: @StoryTeller Well said. And I don't know why I couldn't find it on http://en.cppreference.com last night it's totally here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Answer (score 2):

Your design has a bad smell in it. Storing `item*` has the unfortunate cost of having to manage them outside the `vector`. The only good motivation for a `vector<item*>` would be to use the `item`s [polymorphically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). By trying to detect the type you're demonstrating that you are *not* using them polymorphically.

A better solution would be to store these items in separate vectors, rather than a communal `vector<item*> items`, so `vector<weapon> weapons`, `vector<potion> potions`, `vector<armor> armors`.

So please don't use this code, but given `vector<item*> items` you can do this:

```
for(auto i : items) {
    if(dynamic_cast<weapon*>(i) != nullptr) {
        auto iWeapon = static_cast<weapon*>(i);
        // work with weapon here
    } else if(dynamic_cast<potion*>(i) != nullptr) {
        auto iPotion = static_cast<potion*>(i);
        // work with potion here
    } else {
        assert(dynamic_cast<armor*>(i) != nullptr);
        auto iArmor = static_cast<armor*>(i);
        // work with armor here
    }
}
```

Comment: Separate vectors does make it cleaner. I'll try this out, too. Thanks.

Comment: @Phil Generally when you see all the `dynamic_cast`s it's a tip off that templatization should be used.