# Change return type of base-class's method in its derived-classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, covariance

I know this is not possible if the modified return value is not co-variant with the one in the base class. Still, I'd like to implement something that works that way!

For my specific problem I need some sort of Object called `Node` with a **value** that can range from `int` to `double` to `char` or whatever and then I need to build a container (`std::vector`) of these `Node`s that can flexibly accept any type of `Node`.

I build `Node` essentially as an empty class (it has something in the real code which is common for all its derived classes but is not useful for this post) and specified two types, `NodeInt` and `NodeDouble` that inherit from it.

I then build my class `Container` with the vector as a member. Now I want to be able to loop through all the elements inside my `Container` and have their `value` returned ... how do I do this?

This was my first attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Node{

};

class NodeChar : public Node{

    public:
        NodeChar(){ value = 'a'; }
        double getValue(){ return value; }

    private:
        double value;

};

class NodeInt : public Node{

    public:
        NodeInt(){ value = 5; }
        int getValue(){ return value; }

    private:
        int value;

};

class Collection{

  public:
    Collection( std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec ){ nodeCollection = vec ; }
    void setNodes( std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec ){ nodeCollection = vec ; }
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > getNodes(){ return nodeCollection; }
  private:
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > nodeCollection;    

};


int main() {

    NodeInt n1;
    NodeChar n2;

    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec (2) ;
    vec[0] = std::make_shared<Node>(n1);
    vec[1] = std::make_shared<Node>(n2);

    Collection C(vec);

    std::cout << (C.getNodes())[0]->getValue() << "  ---  " << 
        (C.getNodes())[1]->getValue() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But of course this way gcc complains because `‘class Node’ has no member named ‘getValue’`. I need to have at least a `virtual` method there so that my program knows that each `Node` will have its own `getValue`.

As soon as I go and try to specify its value though I need to return **something** ... and that's a problem!

I solved the problem in two ways, both of which seem unnecessarily complex and ugly ...

### ONE

Using a generic pointer `void*` as a return value and then casting them correctly in a second moment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Node{

    public:
        virtual void* getValue() = 0 ;

};

class NodeChar : public Node{

    public:
        NodeChar(){ value = 'a'; }
        NodeChar( char v ){ value = v; }

        void* getValue(){ return &value; }

    private:
        char value;

};

class NodeInt : public Node{

    public:
        NodeInt(){ value = 5; }
        NodeInt( int v ){ value = v; }
        void* getValue(){ return &value; }

    private:
        int value;

};

class Collection{

  public:
    Collection( std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec ){ nodeCollection = vec ; }
    void setNodes( std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec ){ nodeCollection = vec ; }
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > getNodes(){ return nodeCollection; }
  private:
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > nodeCollection;    

};


int main() {

    NodeInt n1;
    NodeChar n2;

    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec (2) ;
    vec[0] = std::make_shared<NodeInt>(n1);
    vec[1] = std::make_shared<NodeChar>(n2);

    Collection C(vec);

    int* jnk1 = static_cast<int*>((C.getNodes())[0]->getValue());
    char* jnk2 = static_cast<char*>((C.getNodes())[1]->getValue());

    std::cout << *jnk1 << "  ---  " << *jnk2 << std::endl;

    // can't seem to make it work with shared pointers rather than standard int* or double* for the conversion from void*

    return 0;
}
```

### TWO

Essentially the same but returning `void` (so nothing) but requiring as an argument a generic pointer `void*` to be updated in the method. This needs again casting it back ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Node{

    public:
        virtual void getValue( void *& ptr ){}

};

class NodeChar : public Node{

    public:
        NodeChar(){ value = 'a'; }
        NodeChar( double v ){ value = v; }

        void getValue( void *& ptr ){ ptr = &value; }

    private:
        char value;

};

class NodeInt : public Node{

    public:
        NodeInt(){ value = 5; }
        NodeInt( int v ){ value = v; }
        void getValue( void *& ptr ){ ptr = &value; }

    private:
        int value;

};

class Collection{

  public:
    Collection( std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec ){ nodeCollection = vec ; }
    void setNodes( std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec ){ nodeCollection = vec ; }
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > getNodes(){ return nodeCollection; }
  private:
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > nodeCollection;    

};


int main() {

    NodeInt n1;
    NodeChar n2;

    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Node> > vec (2) ;
    vec[0] = std::make_shared<NodeInt>(n1);
    vec[1] = std::make_shared<NodeChar>(n2);

    Collection C(vec);

    void* jnk1 ; (C.getNodes())[0]->getValue(jnk1); 
    int* n1ptr = static_cast<int*>(jnk1);
    void* jnk2 ; (C.getNodes())[1]->getValue(jnk2); 
    char* n2ptr = static_cast<char*>(jnk2);

    std::cout << *(n1ptr) << "  ---  " << *(n2ptr) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is(are?) this the only way to make it work? Is there any better solution you can think of or any other way to implement the same thing (i.e. a virtual method in the base class that has different non-covariant return values depending on the derived classes)?

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comment another way could be using templates, but if I template Node then when I go to build a container I need to have only Node and I cannot use a mix of different specialised classes, hence (if I'm not missing something) this won't solve the problem for me!

Comment: Have you considered using a template, so instead of Node, you define Node<T> and that has a T GetValue()

Comment: In your example you're using knowledge of what type is in each slot to cast appropriately. But the end product won't know that. So, what behaviour do you want from code that receives *N* unknown `Node`s? What should it do with the values? That will guide you towards what kind of solution you need.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts ah! I forgot to mention that I tried, I'll edit OP right away!

Comment: @Quentin well the idea is that as long as I can call the getValue function we can then figure it out! This is not going to be a library for end-users, although I'd love for it to be as generalisable as possible!

Comment: What I mean is that since C++ does not have dynamic typing, you can't just call the function without knowing its return type and go from there. The calling code will have to change, and the most appropriate change depends on what it does with the different types. This can take the form of a chain of `dynamic_cast`s, a Visitor pattern, custom function pointer tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use boost::any, a type safe generic wrapper around any type. When accessing the value you do have to know (or be able to guess) what kind of value you have but it allows you to return any kind of value.

Comment: I didn't know about boost::any! I'd like to avoid too many external libraries but I guess I can make an exception for boost, I'll try to see if I can make it work!

Comment: Works like a charm by just using 
        `class Node{
        public:
      virtual boost::any getValue() = 0; 
    };`
as definition for the Node class in my first code, very simple and elegant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use the **visitor pattern**. Here are some links I have found:

- https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/1
- https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2
- [Visitor Pattern Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116057/visitor-pattern-explanation)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111166/visitor-pattern-in-c-11
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588882/TheplusVisitorplusPatternplusExplained

Essentially, the visitor pattern allows to forward the code to another class that will execute the appropriate function.

So in your case, you could more or less have a class `BaseVisitor` from which you would derive a class `CoutVisitor` for example. Then you would have `visit` function accepting each of the desired types.

For example:

```
void CoutVisitor::Visit(const NodeChar &item)
{
    std::cout << item.getValue();
}
```

Another possibility is to have functions like `getCharValue`, `getDoubleValue,`getValueType` and do appropriate conversion or throw an exception.

Visitor pattern might be more appropriate when operation are complex and the classes (`NodeChar`, `NodeInt`...) are relatively stable.

Multiple functions might works best for things like XML or JSON data representation...