# c++ dynamic return type for function

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I am trying to have a generic class which could return the object of the other class depending on the input to generic class.

From the main function, if I pass in '1' as an argument to the constructor of generic class, i want to be able to get object of child1 class using getType(). My question is: is there a way to change the return type of getType() dynamically or any other way to accomplish this behavior?

My current implementation calls the print() method of base class, even though I create an object of child classes in generic constructor as m_type is a base type.

```
class base {

    public:
        void print(){
            cout << "base\n";
        }
        virtual ~base() {}
};

class child1 : public base {
    public:
        void print(){
            cout << "child1\n";
        }
};

class child2 : public base {
    public:
        void print(){
            cout << "child2\n";
        }
        void hello(){
            cout << "hello from child 2\n";
        }
};

class generic{

    public:
        generic(int b){
            if(b==1) {
                m_type = new child1();
            }
            else if(b==2) 
                m_type = new child2();
        }

    // Somehow return the object of one of the child class based on input 
    // to constructor.
    base *getType(){
        return m_type;
    }

    base *m_type;
};

int main()
{
    generic *g1 = new generic(1);
    // call the method from child1 class instead of base class.
    g1->getType()->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *My current implementation calls the print() method of base class* -- Strange why you would ask this, seeing that you made the destructor in `base` virtual (as it should be).  Were you not aware of what `virtual` means?

Comment: Apologies. Yes, I forgot about the virtual. I want the generic class to return the object of one of the child classes depending on the input.

Comment: It is not possible to do what you're asking for, unless you want to ride the `if()` train, checking to see what type it is or use `dynamic_cast`, again, checking to see if it matches a type.  Otherwise, trying to do what you're asking for sounds like a design flaw.  The part of the code you're making the call to `print` calls for generic usage, but at the same time you want non-generic usage.  Design flaw (IMO).

Comment: You could use a design pattern, such as the [visitor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116057/visitor-pattern-explanation)

Comment: Alternatively: `std::variadic`

Answer (score 1):

Make `print` virtual in `base`.

Non virtual methods do not behave polymorphically.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the virtual. I want the generic class to return the object of one of the child classes depending on the input. I want to call the method of child2 class hello(), which is exclusively in the derived class.

Comment: If you have a base pointer and want to call a function that is only available in the derived class you would generally use `dynamic_cast` to cast to the proper type of pointer then call the function with that pointer if it is not null.

Comment: @st91 if you have a different question ask it; but don't edit an existing valid question to invalidate existing answers.  When asking the new question you should both include a [mcve] **and** describe the actual concrete problem you are solving, unless you want "what you ask for cannot be done".  With both the abstract and concrete, people can solve the concrete problem in a way you do not anticipate.  Without it, they would have to flail randomly.