# Polymorphism with different parameters

Tags: c++

By any chance is it possible to do polymorphism with the same name of function with different parameters?

For example, I want those three functions to become one.

```
virtual bool isValid1(const std::string&) = 0;
virtual bool isValid2(const uint32_t&) = 0;
virtual bool isValid3(const int& num) = 0;
```

In other words, I have a Base `A` and three Derived A class. I also have Base `B` that holds a vector of Base A class and a T(template type, could be a `string`, `unit32` or `int`) argument. When I want to call from Base `B` the `isValid` function using the `vector` and argument (like this: `isValid(argument)`) I am a bit stuck, since I have to know before if to call `isValid1(string)`, `isValid2(uint32)` or  `isValid3(int)`.

Some piece of the code for those who asked,

```
template <class T>
class Field
{
public:
    void addValidator(BaseValidator* validator) { m_validator.push_back(validator); }
    void validate() const { m_validator[0].isValid(m_data);}
private:
    std::vector<BaseValidator*> m_validator;
    T m_data;
};
```

- I am opting for polymorphism, yet other type of solutions are welcome.
- Please let me know if the question is too short to understand, so I can rewrite in a different method.

Comment: Can you show us the inheritance structure instead of describing it?

Comment: would be nice to see some more code or pseudo code to further explain your problem.

Comment: Your `Field::bool validate()` is wrong. For which element in the vector do you want to return the `isValid()`???

Comment: Doubt that's what you want.. Now every time you call `validate()`, you are only calling `isValid()` for the first object. Just pass an `std::size_t elem` to the function.

Answer (score 6):

You can [overload](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/function_overloading) member functions. Even if they are pure virtual and meant to be overriden<sup>1</sup>:

```
virtual bool isValid(const std::string&) = 0;
virtual bool isValid(const uint32_t&) = 0;
virtual bool isValid(const int& num) = 0;
```

Now `isValid(argument)` is going to do overload resolution and pick the overload to call (via dynamic dispatch). The only potential issue is that the last two overloads may be equally good for certain arguments, so the overloading could be ambiguous. But that really depends on the `T` in it's called on.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - That's exactly what [visitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116057/visitor-pattern-explanation) is about, after all.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use the same member function names in the `BaseA` class. This is part of overloading and it is completely valid since after the [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) will help figure out which function you intend to call.

To be precise, the mangled name of each function you create is dependant upon the function name and function parameters.

```
struct BaseA
{
    virtual bool isValid(const std::string&) = 0;
    virtual bool isValid(const uint32_t&) = 0;
    virtual bool isValid(const int &num) = 0;
};
```

The `BaseB::validate() const` function is a bit sketchy. You might want to pass an std::size_t parameter to access the correct element in the vector.

```
virtual bool validate(std::size_t elem) const
{
    return vec[elem]->isValid(var);
}
```

Here's a code example of the final output: https://rextester.com/IHP38905