Classes with interface but different arguments, how to solve? C++
I need to call a set of functions, but what functions are to be called isn't known at compile time. The user decides what kind of calculations he is interested in and then the program takes that input, creates the classes dynamically, puts them in a vector and loops over the vector calling the calculate method to get the result for each calculation. The problem is different calculations require different arguements so I can't really just call calculate for each object in the vector without explicitly checking what kind of object it is. Any way around that?
I have the following class structure:
    class AbstractAB {
    virtual double calculate() = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractAB() = default;

   }



   class AbstractA : public AbstractAB {
    virtual double calculate(int arg_1) = 0;
   }


    class A : public AbstractA {
    
    double calculate(int arg_1) override;


    }


       class AbstractB : public AbstractAB {
        virtual double calculate(int arg_1, double arg_2) = 0;
       }

       class B : public AbstractB {
    
    double calculate(int arg_1, double arg_2) override;


    }

std::shared_ptr<AbstractAB> a = std::make_shared<AbstractAB>(A());
std::shared_ptr<AbstractAB> b = std::make_shared<AbstractAB>(B());
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractAB>> vectr = {a, b};

Now I want to call the method calculate() for each class, but since each class takes different arguments, I cant do that without checking explicitly which class am I dealing with. The following is pseudocode:
for class in vectr:
    class.calculate(arg_1? arg_2? How do i know which to pass?)

I want to avoid the code smell but im not sure how. I looked at Visitor, Command etc, but they don't fix the problem of dynamically deciding what arguments to pass. Something with the structure is wrong, but I can't really put my finger at what. Please, help!

The signature is the function name and the parameter types.  calculate(), calculate(int) and calculate(int,double) are all different.  If you want the interface to support all 3 of those, they should all be expressed in the AbstractAB class.

"How do i know which to pass?" - you don't. You picked a wrong design, if you want to be able to call different versions of calculate using base class pointer, you need to thing of a common interface. Maybe virtual double calculate(std::vector<double> args)=0; ?

Another option is skip the base class and have a std::vector<std::variant<class_types>> and then use the visitor pattern to dispatch to the right function for each object.

Side notes: std::make_unique<AbstractAB>(A()); - unnecessary copy of temporary A(), vectr = {a, b}; - you can't copy unique_ptr, this will not compile, for class in vectr: - this is not even C++, and class is a reserved keyword.

why do you want to stuff objects of different type into the same vector in the first place? Given such a vector, how do you plan to use its elements if you do not know what type it actually is? If you do not have an answer for this (independent of any technical solution) then its not a C++ code issue but one of design.

Hello everyone and thank you for taking the time to answer the question. I have edited the question to better highlight its intent as well as fix some code issues. As everybody correctly noted, this is a design issue but I am unsure where the design is wrong and how to fix it. I want to loop over a vector of objects and call the calculate method of each object. It is a vector because the amount of objects inside it is not known at compile time. For example I may want to calculate just A or both A and B or A, B and C in the future. This is decided by user input.

Note : AbstractAB must have a virtual destructor too

You want to use a vector of variants as argument

Regarding design: Using the visitor pattern has been recommended, some reading: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116057/visitor-pattern-explanation

https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2018/12/29/stop-reimplementing-the-virtual-table-and-start-using-double-dispatch/


I'm going to ignore the top-level "interfaces with different arguments" question entirely, and point out why you don't need that for the original problem you're trying to solve.
There are a couple of ways to approach this.

Postfix aka Reverse Polish

This is an absolute classic, because it's very easy to implement.
Every function just takes a reference to a stack (say std::stack<double>). It pops its arguments off the stack, and then pushes its result on.
Traditionally this requires the user to write 1 2 +, which is handled as stack.push(1); stack.push(2); add(stack). If you can parse the more familiar infix notation 1 + 2 into its syntax tree though, then a depth-first post-order traversal will flatten it into reverse-polish postfix form for you.
This simply side-steps the problem by making every function take the same single parameter.

Infix Calculation / Abstract Syntax Tree

This is what you naturally build when you're parsing infix notation anyway, so we can just use it directly for evaluation. It's more complicated to implement, but perhaps more intuitive.
You have to get the parser to build the syntax tree using nodes that know how to evaluate themselves. This does mean evaluation is naturally recursive rather than iterative, so you may usually have only one root node.
Your parser will have to convert 1 + 2 into a concrete node add with two child nodes, 1 and 2. Each node type will have a name (for the parser to identify it) and a number of inputs required, and each instance of that type will have a container of unique_ptr<AbstractAB> children.
